# How to use deployment manager to deploy across zones

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-deployment-manager

I have found the gcloud command line and api examples of deploying an instance group across multiple zones in a region but it doesn't look like there's anything out there to do the same with deployment manager besides setting the zones you want into an array and iterating through that array in a for loop.  Does anyone have the answer for this? 
Thanks.

Comment: A way to programmatically grab zones in a specified region would also be appreciated.  Thanks again!

Comment: regional clusters are still in beta, deployment manager does not support the beta API for clusters. For the time being, you have to select the zones you want to use, which has the same end effect

Answer (score 0):

On this [GitHub link](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/deploymentmanager-samples/tree/master/examples/v2) you will find an example on how to deploy a load balancer, and how to deploy it across various regions and zones. There are other interesting examples of deployments on that page which could be helpful.

Here is [another example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/deploymentmanager-samples/tree/master/examples/v2/igm-updater) on how to update a managed Instance Group with the deployment manager. There are various examples with jinja, yaml, and python. The instance groups is created in various regions/zones.